# Split string into equal parts using PHP

Tags: php, string

I'd like to get a string, for example 'sdasdasdsdkjsdkdjbskdbvksdbfksjdbfkdbfksdjbf' and split that up every six charaters.

I don't think explode or strtok will work for that?

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should specify what kind of result you want. An array?

Comment: Thanks to everyone else who answered too!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) was designed for just that.

```
$str = "sdasdasdsdkjsdkdjbskdbvksdbfksjdbfkdbfksdjbf";
$parts = str_split($str, 6);
print_r($parts);
```

Answer (score 3):

You want [`chunk_split()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php)

Comment: I am not sure if you understand what does `chunk_split()` do. *It does NOT split string into more strings*, it just splits the string inside itself by mostly adding line-endings after each *chunk*, it is used for a "max-line-length" functionality (e.g. email's body) :)

Comment: This is correct answer if and only if "splitting a string" is considered to mean emitting a single string with embedded linefeeds at locations of the splits. If you want multiple separate strings in an array as the output, you want `str_split()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

See [the docs](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) on `str_split`.

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest way but it works.

```
<?php
$MyString = 'asdfasdlkfjasdlkfjasdlkfjasldkfj';
$MyNewString;
$n = 6; // How many you want before seperation
$MyNewString = substr($MyString,0,$n); 
$i = $n;
while ($i < strlen($MyString)) {
        $MyNewString .= '-'; // Seperator Character
        $MyNewString .= substr($MyString,$i,$n);
        $i = $i + $n;
}
echo $MyNewString
?>
```

Comment: Or just `chunk_split($input, 6, "-")` if you don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$i = 0; $len = 6; $bits = array();
while($i < strlen($str)) {
    $bits[] = substr($str, $i, $len);
    $i += $len;
}
```

Edit: or use str_split as suggested (php has too many functions built in ffs!)

Comment: And people are too happy to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: But the wheel is an extremely useful tool that we would be hard pressed to live without.   I wonder how much overhead these thousands of rarely used functions cost.  I came across the function date_sunrise() in the manual the other day, come on that's ridiculous!

Comment: Because 6 lines of dense PHP code are less overhead than a single function that takes up only a few bytes in compiled form...? :) Sure, it doesn't make sense to include a function for **everything**, but both `str_split` and `date_sunrise` are sufficiently complex to warrant it, and are (quite apparently) getting used every once in a while. `date_sunrise` maybe not that often, but when you do need it, you'll be thankful somebody did the work already.

Comment: The only problem with `date_sunrise()` and friends is that they spam the global namespace for pretty esoteric things. I'm writing this over 10 years later and PHP still hasn't moved all the historical cruft to any namespace prefix even though it would be perfectly well supported in the language today. I guess the official response would be "backwards compatibility".