# Insert separators into a string in regular intervals

Tags: php, regex, recursion

I have the following string in php:

```
$string = 'FEDCBA9876543210';
```

The string can be have 2 or more (I mean **more**) hexadecimal characters
I wanted to group string by 2 like :

```
$output_string = 'FE:DC:BA:98:76:54:32:10';
```

I wanted to use regex for that, I think I saw a way to do like "recursive regex" but I can't remember it.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: There **definitely** is no need for a recursive regex here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't need to check the content, there is no use for regex.

Try this

```
$outputString = chunk_split($string, 2, ":");
// generates: FE:DC:BA:98:76:54:32:10:
```

You might need to remove the last ":".

Or this :

```
$outputString = implode(":", str_split($string, 2));
// generates: FE:DC:BA:98:76:54:32:10
```

---

**Resources :**

- [www.w3schools.com - chunk_split()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_chunk_split.asp)
- [www.w3schools.com - str_split()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_split.asp)
- [www.w3schools.com - implode()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp)

**On the same topic :**

- [Split string into equal parts using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794006/split-string-into-equal-parts-using-php)

Comment: For removing last `:` use this: `rtrim(chunk_split($string, 2, ":"), ":");`

Comment: Please explain the difference b/w these two methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure there are two or more hex characters doing this:

```
if (preg_match('!^\d*[A-F]\d*[A-F][\dA-F]*$!i', $string)) {
  ...
}
```

No need for a recursive regex. By the way, recursive regex is a contradiction in terms. As a regular language (which a regex parses) can't be recursive, by definition.

If you want to also group the characters in pairs with colons in between, ignoring the two hex characters for a second, use:

```
if (preg_match('!^[\dA-F]{2}(?::[A-F][\dA-F]{2})*$!i', $string)) {
  ...
}
```

Now if you want to add the condition requiring tow hex characters, use a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
if (preg_match('!^(?=[\d:]*[A-F][\d:]*[A-F])[\dA-F]{2}(?::[A-F][\dA-F]{2})*$!i', $string)) {
  ...
}
```

To explain how this works, the first thing it does it that it checks (with a positive lookahead ie `(?=...)` that you have zero or more digits or colons followed by a hex letter followed by zero or more digits or colons and then a letter. This will ensure there will be two hex letters in the expression.

After the positive lookahead is the original expression that makes sure the string is pairs of hex digits.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a regex like this:

```
/([0-9a-f]{2})/${1}:/gi
```

Which, in PHP is...

```
<?php
$string = 'FE:DC:BA:98:76:54:32:10';
$pattern = '/([0-9A-F]{2})/gi';
$replacement = '${1}:';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Please note the above code is currently untested.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive regular expressions are usually not possible. You may use a regular expression recursively on the results of a previous regular expression, but most regular expression grammars will not allow recursivity. This is the main reason why regular expressions are almost always inadequate for parsing stuff like HTML. Anyways, what you need doesn't need any kind of recursivity.

What you want, simply, is to match a group multiple times. This is quite simple:

```
preg_match_all("/([a-z0-9]{2})+/i", $string, $matches);
```

This will fill `$matches` will all occurrences of two hexadecimal digits (in a case-insensitive way). To replace them, use preg_replace:

```
echo preg_replace("/([a-z0-9]{2})/i", $string, '\1:');
```

There will probably be one ':' too much at the end, you can strip it with `substr`:

```
echo substr(preg_replace("/([a-z0-9]{2})/i", $string, '\1:'), 0, -1);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php ;) Please don't use it though!

Comment: Some regex implementations support recursive "calls/matches" to previously matched groups (Perl, PHP and .NET support this).

Comment: And what is your definition of a, or the, "regular expression grammar"?

Comment: @Bart K. The "regular expression grammar" is the language you use when you do regular expressions.

Comment: @zneak, okay, but my point is (was) that there is no single regex grammar: each language uses its own regex-flavor. And when talking about a the "true" regular expressions ("true" as in a mathematical sense), then the groupings of matches is not a part of the grammar. So since you were using matching-groups and were talking about things that were not a part of a grammar, I was just wondering what grammar you were talking about.

Comment: @Bart K. I honestly thought no regex flavor had recursivity. Though, it seems I'm wrong.

Comment: @zneak, yes, your comment about recursion in regular expression is incorrect but your comment that there would be a "regular expression grammar" also makes little sense to me since every language  has its own features (and therefor its own grammar). All in all, I'd either remove this post in its current form, or edit it so that the errors in it are removed. Now it can only accumulate downvotes.

Comment: @Bart K. I'm fine with accumulating downvotes with this one. If you still don't like the answer after my edits, feel free to edit it or delete it or downvote it.

Comment: @zneak, no, I can't delete other people's answers. But your answer in its current form is better than it was (I removed my down vote).

Answer (score 0):

While it is not horrible practice to use `rtrim(chunk_split($string, 2, ':'), ':')`, I prefer to use direct techniques that avoid "mopping up" after making modifications.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RHIaJ))

```
$string = 'FEDCBA9876543210';
echo preg_replace('~[\dA-F]{2}(?!$)\K~', ':', $string);
```

Output:

```
FE:DC:BA:98:76:54:32:10
```

Don't be intimidated by the regex.  The pattern says:

```
[\dA-F]{2}   # match exactly two numeric or A through F characters
(?!$)        # that is not located at the end of the string
\K           # restart the fullstring match
```

When I say "restart the fullstring match" I mean "forget the previously matched characters and start matching from this point forward".  Because there are no additional characters matched after `\K`, the pattern effectively delivers the zero-width position where the colon should be inserted.  In this way, no original characters are lost in the replacement.