# convert String to time in hh:mm time format in php

Tags: php

I have a string like-

```
$strTime = "0920"
```

How to convert the above string to time format in PHP-

```
0920 -> 09:20
```

I am super new to PHP so may be this is a very basic question, I tried with strtotime method but it didn't give me the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this fastest solution:

```
$strTime = "0920";
echo $strTime[0] . $strTime[1] . ':' . $strTime[2] . $strTime[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the format will always be the same you can do it literally:

I found an example here: [Split string into 2 pieces by length using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822683/split-string-into-2-pieces-by-length-using-php)

```
$a = ":"
$first400 = substr($str, 0, 2);
$theRest = substr($str, 2);
```

Then create the new time string:

```
echo "$first400{$a}$theRest"
```

I used basic string mania from here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php
You could do some basic checks to make sure it's formatted correctly. Ex if it is 4 chars in length.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime()` gives you the number of seconds since January 1 1970. 920 seconds from that cold, dark birth of time is not the specific time you're looking for.

If you *really* want that string as your output, with the colon in the middle, I would use just inject the colon into the string with `substr_replace()`