# Split up value /3

Tags: php

I have stored a value in sql that is equal to 123196198.

This is actually 3 values that I would like to be split up.
If I do it like this it will work fine

```
$made_of = "123196198";
$var1 = substr($made_of, 0, 3);
$var2 = substr($made_of, 3, 3);
$var3 = substr($made_of, 6, 3);
```

And than use the $var to do what I want.
However, there are others that do not contain 3. They could contain 10, the could contain 1. If I enter more of these sentences, it result in a php error. How can I do this without it resulting in an error?

Comment: 1. Should I even ask why don't you save the values in multiple rows?! 2. Do you want them in separated variables or can it also be in an array?

Comment: 1. It would be extremely much more work to store them in multiple rows
2. What I want to do to them is to print them out if they exists inside a HTML table. 3. They are all stored in 3s

Comment: And which pattern is behind this code? (You know the third param is the length ?)

Comment: Oh. Haha. I'll change that right away. Pattern? HTML table? I don't follow...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string into equal parts using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794006/split-string-into-equal-parts-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
$made_of = "123196198";

$x=str_split($made_of,3);
print_r($x); //Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => 196 [2] => 198 )
```

Comment: that php, its got a function for everything

Comment: Uhm. May I ask how I use a (empty($3[0]) ? Can't make it work :(

Comment: @HaraldOve don't understand the question.