# MySQL search on a field but remove all non-numeric characters

Tags: mysql, sql, database, string, where-clause

Is it possible to search a table but preformat the field in the query to only match on numbers... For example, I am storing the phone number as (123) 555-1234

When someone searches `LIKE '%123555%'` it will not return as you can see.

How can I write a sql query to preformat the field value before searching it...

```
SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE FormatFieldHere(phoneNumber) LIKE '%123555%'
```

Comment: This might not be possible in your use case, but could you store the telephone numbers as a plain string of numbers without formatting and then format them before presentation? That way, your telephone numbers will be searchable with the syntax you gave above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1794075/2154871 look at this answer on how to split the users input, you would then piece it back together applying the brackets and hypen, that said I would look at changing how its stored to make it simpler. infact, change how its searched, force the user to use two fields which you combine them into a formatted search query much easier than splitting then formatting

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL 8.0, you can use [function `REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) to get rid of all non-digit characters before doing the comparison, like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Contacts 
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(phoneNumber, '[^0-9]', '') LIKE '%123555%'
```

Regexp `'[^0-9]'` means: everything but a digit. With this technique, you do not need to explictly list each and every character that you want to ignore.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is not a regex replace function in **MySql**, you can do what you need if you remove all non numeric characters from the phone number by multiple `replace()`:

```
SELECT * FROM Contacts 
WHERE replace(replace(replace(replace(phoneNumber, '(', ''), ')', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') LIKE '%123555%'
```

Answer (score 0):

a other way is to create a PERSISTENT VIRTUAL COLUMN where mysql automatic stores the normalized phone number like this. the can do with the function from GMB describe.

Note: the function to create the virtual column is for MariaDB an i am not sure if it the same syntax in MySQL

Then you can use you function like :

```
SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE FormatFieldHere(phoneNumber) LIKE '%123555%'
```

**sample**

**Create a Table and insert rows**

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE `Contacts` (
    ->   `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `phoneNumber` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.034 sec)

MariaDB [test]> 
MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO `Contacts` (`id`, `phoneNumber`)
    -> VALUES
    -> (1, '(123) 555-1234'),
    -> (2, '+49 2163 9988-111');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.005 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**see the rows**

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM `Contacts`;
+----+-------------------+
| id | phoneNumber       |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | (123) 555-1234    |
|  2 | +49 2163 9988-111 |
+----+-------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

**add Virtual Column and a INDEX and see the new rows**

```
MariaDB [test]> ALTER TABLE `Contacts`
    -> ADD COLUMN
    -> `phoneNumberN` VARCHAR(32) AS ( REGEXP_REPLACE(`phoneNumber`, '[^0-9]', '') ) PERSISTENT;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.032 sec)              
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]> ALTER TABLE `Contacts`
    -> ADD KEY
    -> `IDX_phoneNumberN` (`phoneNumberN`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.036 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM `Contacts`;
+----+-------------------+---------------+
| id | phoneNumber       | phoneNumberN  |
+----+-------------------+---------------+
|  1 | (123) 555-1234    | 1235551234    |
|  2 | +49 2163 9988-111 | 4921639988111 |
+----+-------------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

**add 2 other test rows**

```
MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO `Contacts` (`id`, `phoneNumber`)
    -> VALUES
    -> (3, '222 (123) 555-1234'),
    -> (4, '222 +49 2163 9988-111');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.029 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**SELECT on the new COLUMN**

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT * from `Contacts` WHERE `phoneNumberN` LIKE '%123555%';
+----+--------------------+---------------+
| id | phoneNumber        | phoneNumberN  |
+----+--------------------+---------------+
|  1 | (123) 555-1234     | 1235551234    |
|  3 | 222 (123) 555-1234 | 2221235551234 |
+----+--------------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```