# Auto insert Paragraphs <P> into non-paragraphed text, using some AI, what can be a possible practice?

Tags: php, automation, artificial-intelligence

I have a DB with multiple textual content I display for my site visitors.
A lot of this content is not paragraphed, so it is harder to read, and perhaps also bad for SEO.

Is there any efficient practice that can intelligently insert `<P>` and `</P>` tags, to make the text more user friendly?

preferably something that can be done with PHP framework

Comment: why the downvote :(

Comment: You should do this in the front end rather than adding html to data.

Comment: alright. but still, what kind of script and logic are common for this task?

Comment: What criteria should be used to determine paragraphs? Line endings or `<br>` elements might work, but every line will become a paragraph.

Comment: that's exactly the question.one approach is maybe to combine a count of minimum of characters and at least 3 sentences that end with a `.`. question is whether it can be done with some better approach .

Comment: Hacking text apart by such arbitrary measures is not going to increase understandability. Unless you can get yourself an AI that actually understands the _meaning_ of the text, this is still a job for a human.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1794018/1684254) splits strings at intervals of 6 chars, You should arbitrarily pick how long the intervals you want.. And then append 
 or

and rejoin them.

This isn't a good solution imho.